# Programmable Induction Hotplate

Tags: arduino

I'm looking for an induction hotplate that I can control via my own software. 
[image: hotplate]

An RS232 port or something similar would be fine, but I don't mind if it's not RS232. As long as I can write a program to control it. I'd like to be able to switch it on and off (at a certain temperature) using a program.

If I can't get that, I guess I might be able to have a power switch that can be toggled via a program and the induction hotplate will come on at the correct temperature without any human intervention.

[image: switch]

Answer (score 2):

As you have shown an Arduino type device in your photo, you may want to consider to explore the world of Arduino controlled PID devices. I have a stand-alone device which consists of a thermocouple wired to the PID and a solid state relay which is used to turn a heater on and off based on the temperature settings within the PID

The manual method requires that one make settings to match the thermocouple and to set the upper or lower limit of heating or cooling respectively.

I have not explored the Arduino connected versions, but a quick search shows there are quite a few projects making use of this configuration.

Comment: Interesting, I found this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vTirU8FKCVw
However I should note that I am not a certified electrician, it's probably not legal/safe for me to do it this way.